# Why was this question hated by the community?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, specific-question

I was digging into my old posts to see if I could improve them. There was a question:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82449/.

Though it is deleted but the high rep users might be able to read it.

> What I do not understand is that what was wrong with this post?

After it was deleted by the community mod I asked [the same question on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/595538/) and got an excellent answer that I was looking for. It could be that it is more a mathematical question but if this was the case why wasn't it closed or migrated? Neither the question was closed as *unclear*. Was it downvoted because it is a beginner question? Why was this question not well received by the physics community? I do not see some severe grammatical mistakes beside capitalization.
I am asking this question only because I want to understand how should I present my posts to the physics community so that they be well received.

Comment: It looks to me as if it was automatically deleted for being [more than 30 days old with more than one downvote and no answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/).

Answer (score 3):

The first version required the user to find a book and read it:

> Has anyone read e.spenke's book? what's mathematical definition of mean free time for metal?

The second one was very unclear:

> E.spenke:-"if on the average, a time T elapsed between two collisions
>   of an electron, dt/T terminal points of such times fall on average
>   into the time interval dt. thus an electron suffers in the interval dt
>   on the average dt/T collisions, and N electrons suffer N.dt/T
>   collisions. thus collisions eliminate in an interval dt on the average
>   dN= N.dt/T electrons from a group with uniform velocity hence decrease
>   exponentialy with time: N=N(0).e^(-t/T)
>
> i think dt/T is the probability of an electron to collide here. but
>   can it be shown mathematically?

It also was rather badly formatted, and this makes people less likely to read it. Someone improved it for you, though, and you made further improvements to it. However, it was a bit late by then, and people had already seen the post and may not have checked again for improvements. (also, if it has a score <-3, it gets hidden from the main page)

I also suggest you keep titles descriptive of the actual question.

Comment: What do you think about the latest version? Is it still unclear? "_people had already seen the post and may not have checked again for improvements._"- Do you mean the reviewers might not have checked?

Comment: In general suppose I edit my post after a long time I originally posted it. Would that edit be worth? Would people check it again? I do have some posts which are quite old(including the deleted one's). I am thinking to improve them by editing. How much chances are there that after I edit them people might check them again?

Comment: I would have upvoted the latest version had you not deleted it. This might have contributed to you not getting answers/votes, don't delete posts like this. Otherwise I've seen plenty of late-improve posts getting votes.

Comment: Sorry!? I didn't delete it. It was automatically deleted by comm mod.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, it might have been possible to bounty it, I didn't notice it was autodeleted.

Comment: I would bounty it if I had enough rep.

Comment: I cannot see the my edit history of deleted posts. Is it a bug? When I click on any of the revision link it gives me error 404.

Comment: @user31782 I can undelete it if you want